# How to set datetime format for SQL Server PHP driver

Tags: ubuntu, php, sql-server

In my PHP script, I want to add a date to a column (of type datetime) in MS SQL Server. I set up the connection following this blog post (php5-sybase, php5-odbc, freetds on Ubuntu 14.04/15.10):
https://blog.thesysadmins.co.uk/ubuntu-server-connect-to-mssql-via-php.html

My problem is, using the exact same query in a php script as in SQL Management Studio, the query via PHP fails, because the date column is interpreted as NULL. The (abbreviated) query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_test (mydate) VALUES (’20-3-2004′)
message: Cannot insert the value NULL into column ‘mydate’ column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

As I said, the exact same query runs fine in SQL Management Studio. Now, this query runs without errors:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_test (mydate) VALUES (’3-20-2004′)
```

**Obviously**, the datetime in the Query is interpreted as *M-D-Y*, but I can't find any option to change that. Surprisingly, it works under Ubuntu 15.10, but not on 14.04, using the same config for apache, php. freetds and php5-odbc use their default values.

Neither SQL Server settings (@@LANGUAGE = Germand, sp_helplanguage German dateformat = dmy) nor **php.ini** (iconv datetime formats) have *M-D-Y* configured. **mssql.datetimeconvert = On** makes no difference to being Off.

**tl;dr How do I tell PHP the datetime format isn't MDY but DMY?**

Comment: You could try using convert() with style 3 for dates without century (yy) or 103 with century (yyyy) - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: Yes, that works. But that's only a workaround (for me at least). Or is it best practice to explicitly CONVERT all dates in the query? Genuinely asking, since I'm not an expert on MSSQL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause was neither PHP, nor freetds, or any *NIX system setting. The well-documented `/etc/freetds/locales.conf` for setting the datetime format works fine.

**BUT FOR THE FREETDS DRIVER TO INTERPRET DATES IN THE SPECIFIED FORMAT, YOU MUST NOT ENCODE IT AS A CHARACTER STRING IN YOUR QUERY**

As you can see above in my question, the value for the field of type *datetime* is enclosed in single quotes / ticks. This way, FreeTDS interprets the data as a String (varchar to be precise) and just passes it on the the SQL Server. Which is why the query fails, because the SQL-Server rightfully doesn't allow varchars to be inserted into datetime columns.

Why the exact same query worked on one version of Ubuntu, but not the other is beyond my comprehension.

tl;dr Dont use quotes around datetime values in your queries.
Took me just 3 months to realise :)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments using [convert()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) is a workaround.  I am not an expert in MS SQL.  I mostly use MySQL.  However looking it up, [MS SQL datetime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms186724.aspx) uses the format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

There is `SET DATEFORMAT` for [setting the order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms189491.aspx) of the month, day, and year date parts for interpreting date, smalldatetime, datetime, datetime2 and datetimeoffset character strings.

`SET DATEFORMAT dmy;` should perform the task you need

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I'm still wondering why the query works on Ubuntu 15.04, but not on Ubuntu 14.04. They have different versions of freetds in their repositories, but I didn't find any changelog stating the expected date format has changed. But I've pretty much given up on freetds mssql support. Hope Microsoft will release a stable driver for PHP7 in the not-too-distant future: https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/tree/PHP-7.0-Linux